# Passing complex type as parameter of action method. MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a problem with passing data to action method. I created action link in my view in the way shown below:

```
@model ComplexModel

...

<a href=@Url.Action( "ComplexAction", "ComplexController", new { complex= @Model, str = "string" } )
class="ui-btn">!!!Change all</a>
```

And action method with to get all passed parameters:

```
public ActionResult ComplexAction( ComplexModeloAufgabeViewModel complex, string str )
{
    return View();
}
```

String is passed correctly, but complex model is allways null. What is happening here?

Comment: Because you need to post the complex object with a form. Other wise you need to break the complex object up into its properties and send it in the url to be reconstructed in the action with [FromUrl] attribute.

Comment: Please take a look on the model binding and how it works

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/04/27/6-tips-for-asp-net-mvc-model-binding.aspx

Comment: You cannot pass both as separate route values - `complex= @Model` results in `?complex=yourAssembly.ComplexModeloAufgabeViewModel`. But since you using a view model, then that view model should contain a property `string str` and then its `@Url.Action("ComplexAction", "ComplexController",  Model)` which will generate a query string value for each property if the model contains only simple value types (it will not work if any properties of the model are complex objects or collections).

Comment: But why would you consider doing this - apart from the ugly query string in the url, you risk exceeding the query string limit and throwing an exception. Just pass the `id` of the model and get it in the controller again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to post complex types with a form:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("ComplexAction", "ComplexController")
{
    // form fields go here

    <input type="submit" value="save" />
}
```

This will post your complex type as defined by your ViewModel `@model ComplexViewModel` at the top of your View.

Your action will then read the ViewModel as follows:

```
public ActionResult ComplexAction(ComplexViewModel model)
{
    // do stuff with the form values here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a form in order for the model binder to work

```
@model SomeComplexViewModel

@using Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller")
{
   // fields for every one of the complex type properties
   Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.FirstProperty)

   <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

And then in the action method you will receive your model